# processing a variable size map in pig

Tags: parsing, dictionary, apache-pig

I have a data set that is incoming as

```
(str,[[40,74],[50,75],[60,73],[70,43]])
```

and I need to be able to get this in the output variable using pig:

```
str, 40, 74

str , 50, 75

str, 60, 73

str, 70, 43
```

and this could be variable set of elements.

Tried with tokenizing and then flatten, but that doesn't help as it creates token using comma. and end up being this way..

```
str , {([[40), (74]), ... }
```

Would any one suggestions on if I could use built in functions or write a UDF for this.

many thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom UDF to parse this.  Assuming your data does not get more complicated than this, you can probably get away with a quick, shallow method of parsing using `String.split` with delimiter `"],["`.